# Arrays for matrices and vectors in Java

Tags: java, arrays, rendering, raytracing

I've to implement a render engine (based on ray tracing) for some course (in Java). A few classes are already given (but I'm free to change everything I want). There're a few Matrix/Vector kind of classes which all use seperate variables for each element. For a 4x4 kind of matrix, it looks ugly and seems to me anti object-oriented. I would use a 2D-array. But Java automatically does a bound check. If I use the arrays instead of the seperate variables could this effect the performance in a serious way? (I know that performance and Java do not always match, but It has to be in Java.) Or is it possible to turn off this safety feature?

Comment: The 4x4 Matrix class has 16 separate floating point member fields (e.g.: float m02,m03,..) instead of a single float[4][4] array. I want to change the separate variables to one 2D-array. But if I want to access for instance element (i,j), Java will automatically checks if (i,j) is in the bounds of the array. So my question is will this be a huge performance bottleneck in the long term (ray-tracing on models with +-1000000 vertices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java indeed checks array bounds automatically. This is good and does not have any performance impact.

> I know that performance and Java do not always match, but It has to be
>   in Java.

This is true and is not true. Java indeed is compiled to byte code that is then being interpreted. However java has a lot of features that optimize your code including Just in time compiling, so in some tests java runs faster than native code.

And the last point: read about [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)